# Passing a variable in React but it is showing error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am learning react and getting this error that onDelete is not defined but the tutorial which i am following is not getting the error.
This is the Code also sharing a snipshot. [Snip shot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2vV3.png)
Can anyone tell me why i am getting this error and how to resolve it

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './todoItem';

export default function Todos(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="my-3 text-center">Todo's List</h3>
        { props.todos.map((todo)=> {
            return <TodoItem todo={todo} onDelete={onDelete}/>})
        }
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where is `onDelete` defined? Is it in the parent component and part of `props`? Should it be `props.onDelete`?

Comment: Its neither the part of the props and i have not defined it yet

Comment: _"why i am getting this error and how to resolve it_": 1) You haven't defined an `onDelete` function 2) Define an `onDelete` function. Maybe the people running the tutorial don't have a linter running.

Comment: verify these three things in the tutorial -
1. are they passing it as a prop?
2. are they importing it from somewhere?
3. are they defining it later in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot defined the props and don't tell them about the props so why this happened.

Updated this

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './todoItem';

export default function Todos(props) {
render(){ //Added
 const { onDelete } = this.props; //Added
  return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="my-3 text-center">Todo's List</h3>
        { props.todos.map((todo)=> {
            return <TodoItem todo={todo} onDelete={onDelete}/>})
        }
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

This is code file to map list items.

https://github.com/mashaimtahir/React/blob/master/todo-app%20v2/src/Components/counters.jsx

This the link of complete todo app.

https://github.com/mashaimtahir/React/tree/master/todo-app%20v2/src